# What is the current term for people who are ethnic Germans who don't live in Germany?

Tags: single-word-request

As someone with an interest in history, I know that there was a time when people of German descent living outside of Germany were called *Volksdeutsche* but I gather this term is now frowned upon due to its linkage with Nazism. How are such people referred to in German now?

This isn't a strictly academic question. My parents were both born and raised in Germany but emigrated overseas after WWII so I'm not sure how to describe myself to German speakers in any brief way. I tend to say something like:

> Meine Eltern waren deutsch geboren, aber ich bin in Kanada geboren und spreche meistens Englisch.

I have to imagine there's a more concise way to describe myself than that. In English, I would tend to say that I'm an ethnic German or maybe German-Canadian.

Let me emphasize that I have NO love for any of the Nazi ideology or policies! I am merely trying to figure out how to say that I have a German heritage. My real name, as opposed to the login name I use here, is very German and people sometimes ask about it. I also have a first name that is more commonly a last name here so people sometimes don't realize I've given them my first name when I introduce myself.

EDIT:
I should have made clear that my German is far from fluent so responses explained in English would be greatly appreciated. Also, I should have mentioned that I have a dual citizenship, Canadian and German.

Comment: The term for people with a German passport living abroad would be "Auslandsdeutsche".

Comment: See also [Aussiedler und Spätaussiedler](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussiedler_und_Sp%C3%A4taussiedler), which refers to (some of) those who use their right to move to Germany due to their heritage, but I think this term is limited to people from ex-communist ruled countries.

Comment: @chaosflaws: seems like the OP's looking for the German equivalent for 'German diaspora', i.e. all people who are ethnically or culturally German (however that's defined), not just who hold German passport.

Comment: In the UK, we call them the monarchy.

Comment: @Strawberry - LOL

Comment: I think the most boring answer for this is probably that for most germans the fact that your parents were german is just not going to be extremely relevant if you yourself aren’t and don’t speak the (or _a_, depending on how you count) german language.

Comment: What about "geborene Deutsche"?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know a single word for that.
I have never heard *Volksdeutsche*. If someone mentioned this to me, I had to ask what exactly is meant. And as you said, it sounds a little strange.
Perhaps there are other short terms but I suggest to put it into some more words, to be understood correctly.

> Ich habe deutsche Wurzeln
> (I have german roots - perhaps this sounds odd in English but is understood in Germany)
>
> Ich bin der Sohn / die Tochter / ein Enkel / ein Nachkomme deutscher Auswanderer
> (I am the son / daughter / grandchild / descendant of german emigrants)
>
> Meine Eltern stammen aus Deutschland, aber ich wurde in Kanada geboren
> (My parents originate from Germany but I was born in Canada)

Comment: "I have German roots" is [absolutely fine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roots:_The_Saga_of_an_American_Family) [note the capital for adjectives derived from proper nouns].

Comment: You must have read not a lot of WW II-era history if you've never heard *Volksdeutsche*?  It's a nazi term, see [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Volksdeutsche&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CVolksdeutsche%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CVolksdeutsche%3B%2Cc0): never used before the 1930s, a lot during the nazi era, and a little after, presumably mostly in history books covering WW II.

Comment: @gerrit Correct, I really am not deep in this subject.

Answer (score 20):

## Deutschstämmige

Obwohl "deutschstämmig" zu ähnlicher Zeit wie [volksdeutsch](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=volksdeutsch%2Cdeutschst%C3%A4mmig&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cvolksdeutsch%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvolksdeutsch%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVolksdeutsch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeutschst%C3%A4mmig%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cvolksdeutsch%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvolksdeutsch%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVolksdeutsch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeutschst%C3%A4mmig%3B%2Cc0) aufkam und ebenfalls 1940 einen Peak hatte, würde ich das Wort als relativ unbelastet betrachten.

Ein wichtiger Unterschied ist, dass *volksdeutsch* für deutschsprachige Minderheiten im Ausland benutzt wurde, die dorthin (Ungarn, Russland, Ukraine) vor teils mehreren hundert Jahren in Gruppen ausgewandert sind, dort Gemeinden bildeten und Sprache, Religion, Kultur zu bewahren versuchten. Einzelne Auswanderer, die sich in die neue Kultur weitgehend integrieren wollen, insbesondere die dortige Sprache übernehmen wollen, nennt man nicht Volksdeutsche.

Außerdem gibt es Gebiete, die vor dem 1. bzw. 2. Weltkrieg zu Deutschland gehörten, etwa Ostpreußen und Schlesien, die nach dem Krieg anderen Staaten zugefallen sind (Polen, Tschechoslowakei) und deren Bewohner mit dem Kriegsende nicht komplett ins dt. Reich bzw. in die DDR oder BRD ausgewandert sind. Von diesen könnte die Rede sein, wenn jmd. den Begriff "volksdeutsch" benutzt, aber meist wird dann das konkrete Gebiet benutzt (Ostpreußen, Masuren, Oberschlesien, ...). Je nach Kontext (Geschichte, Kultur, Recht vs. Politik) ist der Verdacht, dass mit dem Begriff ein ideologischer Standpunkt verbunden wird, weniger oder mehr angebracht.

Umgekehrt sind Volksdeutsche aber deutscher Abstammung und daher Deutschstämmige.

Comment: There is no part of Czechoslovakia that would become part of it after the second world war from Germany. There is only a small part of Altreich that did so in 1920. Other German speaking  areas of Czechoslovakia were parts of Cisleitania before the first world war, not of Germany, they include Bohemia, Moravia and some Austrian remnants of Silesia.

Comment: Stimmt. Habe Änderungen vorgenommen (1. WK).

Comment: Ich bin Deutschschweizer und denke, dass die Definition „ethnic German who don‘t live in Germany“ auf mich zutrifft, da ich ja Alemanne bin, und die zu den Germanen gehören. Aber bin ich deutschstämmig?

Comment: @LangLangC: In vormoderner Geschichte bin ich recht schwach gebildet, entnahm der Wikipedia https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlesien  jedoch, dass es da hin und herging, siehe "Otto I.", "Beginn des 13. Jahrhunderts" u.a. Satz 1, Abs. 3 war ja in der Tat kaputt.

Comment: @wra: Ich glaube nicht, dass eine Definition möglich ist, die für alle Fragestellungen passt. Als Nation ist die Schweiz ja seit sehr langem eine stabile Einheit. Die Differenzierung nach Sprache ist m.W. aber auch sehr stabil. Ich würde weder bei "schweizstämmig", noch bei"deutsch-schweizstämmig" zucken. Würden wir gemeinsam Urlaub in den USA machen, und Du bezeichnetest Dich dort ohne weitere Erklärung als deutschstämmig, würde ich mich wundern. Sowohl von Österrichern, als auch von Schweizern bin ich gewohnt, dass sie sich da gerne etwas abgrenzen.

Comment: Von mir aus würde ich mich nicht als ethnic German bezeichnen, um einer fruchtlosen Diskussion aus dem Weg zu gehen, es aber evtl. schlucken wenn es jmd. anderes benutzt. Der Begriff der Ethnie ist m.W. sehr unscharf, und daher wäre es eine Frage des Kontextes. Friesen, Franken, Alemannen, Bajuwaren, Preußen, Rheinländer - juristisch wird es zunehmend irrelevant. Wo ich herkomme war immer mal wieder Frankreich, ganz früher römisches Reich, aber meine Vorfahren kenne ich nur bis 2 Generationen zurück, Anfang 1900. Wo deren Vorfahren herkamen - k.A. Am Ende bin ich Äthiopier, … Affe, Einzeller.

Comment: I should have made clear that my German is not very good so I'm afraid I don't fully understand the German-language responses. I spoke a little Plattdeutsch as a kid but only started learning Hochdeutsch in university and have had only three short visits to Germany since then so I'm a long way from fluent.

Comment: @Henry: hm, no, not necessarily: you asked in English, thus answers need to come in English as well. Mayby user unknown adds an english version as well.

Comment: Zum Thema "volksdeutsch" gibt es eine interessante Diplomarbeit: http://othes.univie.ac.at/13789/1/2011-02-11_0602030.pdf Vgl. auch https://www.hsozkult.de/conferencereport/id/tagungsberichte-214

Answer (score 8):

IMO too "Volksdeutsche" carries the mentioned historical and ideological ballast. I'd avoid it.

I can't think of a special technical term for the descendants of Germans abroad. The individuals who moved back in the day would certainly have been "Auswanderer" or "Emigranten" (sing. Emigrant/in) from Germany (or naturally "Einwanderer/Immigranten" in Canada). Their descendants are "Nachfahren von Auswanderern/Emigranten" from Germany.

So, just like the @Puck i'd suggest, if you want to introduce yourself with the migration background:

> Ich bin ein Nachfahre deutscher Auswanderer.

and if people in the pub ask for details (just another variant):

> Mein Eltern sind/waren deutsche Auswanderer, aber ich bin in Kanada geboren und spreche meistens englisch.

Of course you can describe yourself as a "German-Canadian" (Deutsch-Kanadier or Deutschkanadier), it'll be understood. German Wikipedia has an entry on "Deutschkanadier".

Comment: I second the use of "Deutschkanadier", which would concisely express the desired meaning.

Comment: This doesn't change the content of the post; it's not part of the answer. As @ShegitBrahm says, it should be a comment under the OP question.

Comment: @a_donda: I thought for 2 seconds to ask you in comment to change it. Then I false-believed I'd seen you having other SE-Profiles (but there is not). So in disbelieve I decided to fix the minor thing I assumed you know already. Help Center: https://german.stackexchange.com/help/behavior  / https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment => with right assumption I would have commented first. My apology to that. In your recent edit I see the reference to Question. Still valid: a question in an answer (=unusual on StackExchange), just can't find the Meta.SE post about.

Comment: Yeah, no problem then. I am a free speech radical :-) I fear that if we start to just wipe out parts in answers we might narrow the information content of this site. You're not my enemy :-) Over & out.

Comment: Enumerating my first name? How does counting it help? I assume you meant to say "altering"?

Comment: No i meant using the 'Murrican :-) customs of I (the first), II (jr.) or so. Germans don't do that. Anyway, now i took out that remark since it confuses more than it it is useful. If your question has been answered and you're content, it is customary to mark one of the answers

Comment: As OP mention in another comment that their German isn't that fluent: "Meine Eltern waren deutsche Auswanderer" implies that the parents are dead (like "My parents were German immigrants [to Canada]"). Wrt. to OP's sentence in the question "Meine [lebenden] Eltern *sind* gebürtig aus Deutschland"/"sind in Deutschland geboren" (somewhat more colloquially) = My parents were born in Germany. (The north of Germany may differ in their choice of tense)

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX: You're right.

Answer (score 4):

As @userunknown already said the best single word term is

[Deutschstämmig](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschst%C3%A4mmige) ([German diaspora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_diaspora))

> Deutschstämmige are ethnic Germans and their descendants living outside Germany. It also refers to the aspects of migration of German speakers from central Europe to different countries around the world. This definition describes the "German" term as a sociolinguistic group as opposed to the national one since the emigrant groups came from different regions with diverse cultural practices and different varieties of German.
>
> Als Deutschstämmige werden im traditionellen Sprachgebrauch Personen bezeichnet, deren Vorfahren Deutsche sind oder waren und die keine deutsche Staatsbürgerschaft besitzen beziehungsweise diese aufgegeben oder verloren haben. Das Attribut deutschstämmig wird meistens auf Personen angewendet, die sich nicht mehr dauerhaft in dem Gebiet aufhalten, in dem ihre Deutsch als Muttersprache sprechenden Vorfahren gelebt haben.

So you are deutschstämmig if

- your ancestors were German
- you are no German citizen
- you are living in a non-German speaking country (take care with this one. It's very ambiguous)

---

**But** no one would say

> Ich bin deutschstämmig. / Ich bin Deutschstämmiger.

For far better formulations take a look at [@pucks answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/56667/what-is-the-current-term-for-people-who-are-ethnic-germans-who-dont-live-in-ger#answer-56669), as they are used in "normal" conversations.

Comment: Du würdest das vielleicht niemals sagen, aber ich bestreite, dass das niemand sagen würde.

Comment: @userunknown Zugegeben, niemals/niemand ist ein hartes Wort, aber "deutschstämmig" ist halt auch nicht so idiomatisch verbreitet, wie etwa "xxx Wurzeln haben" von puck.

Comment: Allerdings sagt man auch nicht "Ich bin Deutschwurzler" oder "wurzeldeutsch". Pucks Variante 2, mehr noch 3 mangelt es an der geforderten Knappheit. Desungeachtet rechtfertigt die idiomatische Verbreitung nicht, dass man aus "weniger" ein "niemand" macht - das ist eine falsche Dichotomie. Zudem muss man berücksichtigen, dass wir uns oft in einer sozialen, regionalen, Alters- und Einstellungsblase bewegen und den Alltagssprachgebrauch anderer, insbes. medial unterrepräsentierter Gruppen, kaum kennen.

Answer (score 4):

English summary: One possibility is the composite word "Auslanddeutsche(r)" which is neutral and well established for people who juristically are or alternatively at least feel German.

Es wurde bis jetzt erst in einem Kommentar erwähnt, aber "Auslanddeutsche(r)" ist ein neutrales durchaus gebräuchliches Wort, es hat zum Beispiel auch einen [Wikipediaartikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslandsdeutsche).

Ich selbst habe es noch nie gehört, aber Auslandschweizer(in) höre ich oft (als Schweizer) und dann macht es nur Sinn dass Auslanddeutsche(r) genauso funktioniert.

Ich würde es vor allem verwenden, wenn auch juristisch die Staatsangehörigkeit vorhanden ist oder man sich zumindest selbst als Angehörige(r) der Nation bezeichnen würde.

Comment: Ja eben, für jemanden, der selbst noch die Staatsangehörigkeit seiner Geburtsnation hat (und eventuell auch nur temporär im Ausland lebt). Aber der Begriff "Auslandsdeutscher" passt eben nicht zu im Ausland geboreren Nachkommen von Auswanderern, so wie es der Fragesteller beschrieben hat.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Es passt nicht in jedem Fall, da stimme ich zu, aber es könnte je nach dem passen und ist in dem Zusammenhang gut zu kennen.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf IANAL, aber der OP hat wahrscheinlich technisch die deutsche Staatsangehörigkeit: [**"Durch die Geburt** erwirbt ein Kind die deutsche Staatsangehörigkeit, wenn ein Elternteil die deutsche Staatsangehörigkeit besitzt."](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stag/__4.html) Ob man das nachweisen kann (duch Pass oder andere Dokumente) beeinflusst den Status nicht.

Comment: I should have made clear that my German is not very good so I'm afraid I don't fully understand the German-language responses. I spoke a little Plattdeutsch as a kid but only started learning Hochdeutsch in university and have had only three short visits to Germany since then so I'm a long way from fluent.

Comment: @Henry I added an English summary. If you don't speak much German, the word probably doesn't fit you, which is also what the other commenters pointed out. But if you are juristically German it's juristically correct.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most boring answer for this is probably that for most germans the fact that your parents were german is just not going to be extremely relevant if you yourself aren’t and don’t speak the (or *a*, depending on how you count) german language. It’d be much faster to explain that your parents were german rather than trying to come up with a possibly ambiguous word to describe your situation.

It’s hard to back this up with statistics, but in my experience most people think it’s at least a bit weird to call yourself german if you’ve not spent a significant amount of time in germany, and would rather think of you as a <country where you grew up in>-native whose parents (or grand parents, or great grandparents depending on who’s asking) just so happened to be from Germany or a german speaking region. Don’t get me wrong, it’s an interesting enough anecdote to tell, but the common opinion I experience is that german-ness is a matter of culture, not heritage.

Comment: "weird to call yourself german if you’ve spent a significant amount of time in germany" - shouldn't this be "if you *have not* spent a significant amount of time in Germany"? Otherwise, I fully agree :)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely right!
Volksdeutsche was the general name for the German national minorities living in Europe before WWII. By the way I've got some friends from Russia, so as I've heard from them: before and during the WWII there was also such a term used towards ethnic Germans, living in Soviet Union in those times - Volksdeutsche - namely before 1945.
You can also find the information in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksdeutsche .
Nowadays, it seems to me, there is just a neutral term used to Germans living abroad, that is German national minority.
"Volksdeutsche war in der Zeit des Nationalsozialismus eine Bezeichnung für außerhalb des Deutschen Reichs in den Grenzen von 1937 und Österreichs lebende Personen deutscher Volkszugehörigkeit und nichtdeutscher Staatsangehörigkeit, vor allem in Ost- und Südosteuropa. Davor war es üblich, sie als „Auslandsdeutsche“ zu bezeichnen." - https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksdeutsche

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Since you provided a link to Wikipedia, you could have included some quotes from there. Like this term was coined by and for Nazi.

Comment: Volksdeutsche war in der Zeit des Nationalsozialismus eine Bezeichnung für außerhalb des Deutschen Reichs in den Grenzen von 1937 und Österreichs lebende Personen deutscher Volkszugehörigkeit und nichtdeutscher Staatsangehörigkeit, vor allem in Ost- und Südosteuropa. Davor war es üblich, sie als „Auslandsdeutsche“ zu bezeichnen. - https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksdeutsche

Comment: Great for that summary. Now please edit this into your answer. My comment is only to help you writing a better answer. by content I doubt this is nowadays a neutral term.